# Chain rule and a function of a function of a function

Tags: derivatives

Suppose we have a composite function: $f(g(h(x)))$, and we want $\frac{\partial f}{\partial h}$.

By the chain rule $\frac{\partial f}{\partial h} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial h}$.

My question is: what about any occurrences of $x$? Do we have to express all the $x$ as functions of $h$? Or even write the $x$s in terms of $g$? Does it make a difference?

$~\\$

For example $f = g\times (x^2+1)$, and $g = h^2; h=1/x^2$. Then

1) $\frac{\partial f}{\partial h} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial h} = (x^2+1)\times 2h$,

or write $f = h^2\times(x^2+1)$, and

2) $\frac{\partial f}{\partial h} = 2h\times(x^2+1)$,

or write $f = h^2\times(1/h+1) = h + h^2$, and

3) $\frac{\partial f}{\partial h} = 1+2h$.

(1) and (2) give the same result, and $x$ is not acted on. What about case (3)?

Comment: I've asked this many times in comments, never got an answer. How do people define derivative with respect to a function?

Comment: $f = f(g(h(x))) = g(h(x))*(x^2 + 1)$. This is just an example, I invented some forms for $g$ and $h$.

Comment: @GitGud I think that is the heart of the issue here. Are they meant to be functional derivatives in the chain rule?

Comment: My opinion is that the symbol $\frac{\partial f}{\partial h}$ has no meaning and I have no idea what is actually meant.

Answer (score 0):

$$f = g(h(x))*(x^2 + 1)$$
$$h(x)=\dfrac{1}{x^2}$$
$$f = g(h(x))*\dfrac{(h(x)) + 1}{(h(x))}$$
Let $h(x)=t$,
$$f = g(t)*\dfrac{t + 1}{t}$$
$$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}=\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial t}\dfrac{t + 1}{t}-g(t)*\dfrac{1}{t^2}$$

Comment: Your f is now wrong, it should read $f = g(h(x))*\frac{h(x)+1}{h(x)}$. Iḿ more interested in the general principle rather than this particular example. Your answer is that we must first write the occurrences of $x$ in terms of h(x), and then start differentiating as per the chain rule?